# Using scholar package with shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to create a shiny web page that will provide bespoke publication lists by manipulating data from Google Scholar. The code below works fine on my own computer but using the shinyapps.io server gives the error "Warning in get_profile(id = scholar.id) : NAs introduced by coercion."

I've checked that the scholar.id is a character variable. It seems like the key get_profile function from the scholar package is not responding.

Here is my minimal UI:

```
library(shiny)
library(scholar)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(inputId = "google.id",
                label = "Google Scholar ID (12 characters)",
                value='lhc97roAAAAJ')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput(outputId = 'h_text')
    ) # end of main panel
)))
```

Here is my minimal server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  source('scholar.R')
  results <- function(){
    results = scholar(scholar.id=input$google.id)
    results
  }
  output$h_text <- renderText({
    paste(results()$name, '.\n',
            results()$affiliation, '.\n')
  })
```

And a minimal version of the key function:

```
scholar = function(scholar.id='lhc97roAAAAJ'){
  ret = list() # start with blank output
  bio = scholar::get_profile(id=scholar.id) # get basics
  name = bio$name
  affiliation = bio$affiliation
  ret$name = name
  ret$affiliation = affiliation
  return(ret)
}
})
```

Comment: Not sure, but don't you need to isolate your input via `req`? I.e. `results = scholar(scholar.id=req(input$google.id))`? See here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html

Comment: If I add the function inside the script and run the app as a single file (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/single-file.html) it works fine for me. Are you able to use the `get_profile` function outside of the app? Is `req` not dependent on there being no output to begin with?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting an error (see here https://aushsi.shinyapps.io/scholar-simple/). I've tried using a single file with the function to call scholar in the server function. I wonder if it is the delay for the results to be returned to the get_profile function that's causing the issue.

Comment: I've narrowed down the error to the GET function from httr and it looks like this thread might provide the answer https://github.com/hadley/httr/issues/215